# Problem in connectivity with mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying connectivity with mysql in php. But it shows an error message at this line.

```
 $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','admin');
```

fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/search?q=call+do+undefined+function+mysql_connect&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: what version of php & mysql, do you have them all installed correctly, what os are you on?

Comment: php5.3.6, mysql5.5 and Windows OS. And yes all are properly installed

Comment: try this <?php phpinfo(); exit(); ?> and search for MySQL , if its not there then install it. Your code is fine

Comment: I searches MqSql and it is found in the path variable only under the environment.But MySql is already install and i have created database also.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the MySQL Extension has not been enabled/installed:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php (the original mysql extension)
or
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php (the newer mysql extension)

P.s. I would recommend skipping those and using PDO :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have MySQL installed ?

Comment: Have you done a phpinfo() to check if the extension has been added

Comment: Yes the extension for mysql is also added in the php.ini file and ddl is also there in the ext folder

Comment: @user99 Are you sure `MySQL` is running when you are trying to see your page in a browser.